# Publicly accessible database for the Autistic brain under MRI and/or fMRI

Tags: neuroscience, psychology, neuroimaging

American neuroscientist James H. Fallon released many of the images of MRIs from diagnosed psychopaths and was able to identify a pattern when compared to the average individual. Is there a database for Autism that can be used in a similar way? If anyone can find a study specifically comparing autism and another type of brain that will be fine, as I seek to compare autistics, neurotypicals, and other different types of neurological disorders identifiable through brain imaging.

Comment: Great question. I know of fMRI studies of both psychopaths and autism but I can't recall any direct comparisons of both. Definitely there has been fMRI studies of autism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not personally familiar with this project (outside my area of research), but a quick search brought me to the Autism Brain Imaging Data Exchange (ABIDE):

http://fcon_1000.projects.nitrc.org/indi/abide/

Based on citation counts for the primary articles, it seems popular. If you want to compare to other types of brains you will probably need to use multiple data sets and combine them.

---

Di Martino, A., Yan, C. G., Li, Q., Denio, E., Castellanos, F. X., Alaerts, K., ... & Deen, B. (2014). The autism brain imaging data exchange: towards a large-scale evaluation of the intrinsic brain architecture in autism. Molecular psychiatry, 19(6), 659. doi: 10.1038/mp.2013.78.

Di Martino, A., O’connor, D., Chen, B., Alaerts, K., Anderson, J. S., Assaf, M., ... & Blanken, L. M. (2017). Enhancing studies of the connectome in autism using the autism brain imaging data exchange II. Scientific data, 4, 170010. doi: 10.1038/sdata.2017.10.